# Celery python logger issue

Tags: python, logging, celery, python-logging

Below snippet of logging system works fine with django application with logs following the required formate, but fails in a celery application

```
logging.config.dictConfig(
    {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "formatters": {
            "json": {
                "format": "%(name)s %(module)s %(filename)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s ",
                "class": "pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter",
            }
        },
        "handlers": {"json": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler", "formatter": "json"}},
        "loggers": {
            "": {"handlers": ["json"], "level": logging.DEBUG}  # Set log level info
        },
    }
)


configure(
    context_class=threadlocal.wrap_dict(dict),
    logger_factory=stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
    wrapper_class=stdlib.BoundLogger,
    processors=[
        stdlib.filter_by_level,
        stdlib.add_logger_name,
        stdlib.add_log_level,
        stdlib.PositionalArgumentsFormatter(),
        processors.TimeStamper(fmt="iso"),
        processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
        processors.format_exc_info,
        processors.UnicodeDecoder(),
        stdlib.render_to_log_kwargs,
    ],
)

log = structlog.getLogger(__name__)
log.info('Log content', input='some input')
```

This fails in the case of my celery standalone application.Basically the pythonjsonlogger configuration is not taking an effect. The logs are coming with default logger settings. Am I missing something. Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: If your problem is that the celery application is ignoring your `logging` configuration, your problem is unrelated to `structlog` and you're unnecessarily limiting the audience of your question.  Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289809/celery-logger-configuration can help?

Comment: @hynek You are right, this was not a structlog issue, at the time my question was framed I had no idea what caused the issue, have made the appropriate changes in the question. Thanks for your comment